# How to join deep data in the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I like to join the OrderItem and Tree via OrderItemSKUID and NodeSKUID.

My query looks like

```
IEnumerable<COM_Order> data = 
    ctx.COM_Order.Include("COM_Customer")
                 .Include("CMS_Tree")
                 .Include("COM_OrderItem");
```

How can I get the Tree?

[image: DB Model]

Comment: have you tried a google search on how to `C# Join 2 Tables Entity Framework` lots of working examples.. please put in a little more effort on your part ..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include command is for lazy loading.  You need to use the join function.  MSDN for Join reference.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534675%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
IEnumerable<COM_Order> data = ctx.COM_OrderItem
                                 .Join(ctx.CMS_Tree, 
                                       co => co.OrderItemSKUID,
                                       t => t.NodeSKUID, 
                                       (orderitem,tree) => {myOrder = orderitem.COM_Order })
                                 .Select(o => o.myOrder)
                                 .AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: since there is a one to many relation from COM_Order to COM_OrderItem, there is no co.OrderItemSKUID.